# Rule outcomes in YARA-L (Google Cloud Chronicle)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yara

I am trying to wrap my head around outcomes section in YARA-L. Apart from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/chronicle/docs/detection/yara-l-2-0-syntax#outcome_section_syntax), I am also looking at this [blog](https://chronicle.security/blog/posts/new-to-chronicle-rule-outcomes/).

My queries are tied in to the example in the aforementioned blog post.

1. How is the following a single-event rule? The way I am thinking about it, a single-event should be comprised of a single UDM field. But here more than one UDM field is being evaluated to determine if criteria exists for the rule to fire. Can you please help me figure where I am going wrong in thinking about this.
2. The blog post says: *The outcome section will contain values that we want to provide with our detection to add further context to the detection.* What does the latter exactly mean?

**Use of outcome in single event**

```
events:
   $event.metadata.event_type         = "SCAN_FILE"
   $event.security_result.category    = "SOFTWARE_MALICIOUS"
   $event.security_result.action      = $secAction
   $event.security_result.threat_name = $threatname
   $event.security_result.rule_name   = $rulename
   $event.target.file.full_path       = $targetfilepath
outcome:
   $risk_score = max(100 - if($secAction = "QUARANTINE", 50, 0) - if($secAction = "BLOCK", 70, 0))
   $action = array_distinct($secAction)
   $threat = array_distinct($threatname)
   $rule_detection = array_distinct($rulename)
   $file_path = $targetfilepath
   $tlp = "amber"
condition:
   $event and $risk_score > 49
```